# Vb.net modify app config connection string during installation

Tags: vb.net

I have a small vb.net application using window forms with dataset. Currently the database is stored in `c:\`. When I created the MSI package and installed on another workstation, I need to change the database location to a network drive `z:\`, but my connection string in app config is already indicated `C:\` hence resulted in error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net change connection string in app.config during installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255896/vb-net-change-connection-string-in-app-config-during-installation)

Comment: yes but the other thread did not solve the problem. pls help